# How to check the quality of a prediction of new data in a linear model

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, prediction

I have the following linear model:

```
    Call:
    lm(formula = log10(wage) ~ age + occup + sex + edu + occup:sex)
    Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)  0.7026881  0.1056301   6.652 1.99e-10 ***
    age          0.0038949  0.0009635   4.042 7.17e-05 ***
    occup2      -0.1536263  0.0635195  -2.419 0.016340 *  
    occup3      -0.2336201  0.0621690  -3.758 0.000216 ***
    occup4      -0.2491035  0.0637374  -3.908 0.000121 ***
    occup5      -0.1355834  0.0536633  -2.527 0.012174 *  
    occup6      -0.1587712  0.0514086  -3.088 0.002253 ** 
    sex1        -0.1627593  0.0791641  -2.056 0.040885 *  
    edu          0.0200666  0.0051233   3.917 0.000118 ***
    occup2:sex1 -0.1218986  0.1069351  -1.140 0.255471    
    occup3:sex1  0.1146085  0.0947847   1.209 0.227817    
    occup4:sex1  0.0001714  0.0969600   0.002 0.998591    
    occup5:sex1  0.1494844  0.0919501   1.626 0.105346    
    occup6:sex1 -0.0758711  0.0928104  -0.817 0.414476
```

Where occup and sex are categorical variables. If I predict the following dat I get:

```
    A = c(6.5,45,20,8,0,1,1,6)
    B = c(10.2,35,10,10,1,2,0,1)
    new <- data.frame(age=c(A[2],B[2]),exper=c(A[3],B[3]),edu=c(A[4],B[4]),sex=c(A[5],B[5]),ethnic=c(A[6],B[6]),sector=c(A[7],B[7]),occup=c(A[8],B[8]))  
    new$sex = as.factor(new$sex)
    new$ethnic = as.factor(new$ethnic)
    new$sector = as.factor(new$sector)
    new$occup = as.factor(new$occup)
    prediction = predict(wage.trans2,new);prediction
    1         2 
    0.8797188 0.8769151 
    log10(6.5)
    0.8129134 # correct value for 1
    log10(10.2)
    1.0086    # correct value for 2
```

I know that the bottom two numbers are correct, how can I check the quality of this prediction?

Answer (score 1):

If the values used in prediction (i.e the values in A and B) are part of the training data then the quality of prediction can be checked by seeing how far it is away from the actual observation. Technically, this wouldn't have much use for prediction/forecasting on new data.

On the other hand, if they are not part of the training data, then AFAIK all you have is the confidence interval and prediction interval. As the values used in predictions move far away from their mean values, the quality of prediction goes down i.e the interval widens - the **quality of prediction is better if your interval is small**. You can look into [this](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/4/5) to understand how prediction interval is calculated.

Comment: More importantly, one would want to *quantify* the "quality of prediction": that's the sense in which this question deserves to be answered.  Do you have any specific proposals to do that?

Comment: @whuber have edited the answer, hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you, but you still have not provided any quantitative advice at all.  Terms like "far away" and "small," although evocative, are merely *qualitative*.  They are of little help in actually performing statistical analysis.

Comment: @whuber , thanks for pointing out what was missing. You can look into [this](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/4/5) to understand how prediction interval is calculated.

Comment: I have contributed several posts on this site about prediction intervals and their calculation--but that is not germane to this conversation. If you provide only a qualitative answer, it's likely to be perceived as having little value or even misperceived as being incorrect.  I would encourage you to consider improving your post so that it provides relevant and useful information.

Comment: I am new to the field of statistics and Data Science, and thats all that I know about it. Feel free to edit my answer, down vote, report it  or post a new one, that would be really helpful for me or anyone that has the same question. Thanks in advance :)